# solving recurrence T(n) = T(√n) + theta((lg lg n))

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, master-theorem

My solution:
let m = lg n. Then n = 2^m. T(2^m) = T(2^(m/2)) + theta(lgm). Let S(m) = T(2^m). Then S(m) = S(m/2) + theta(lgm). Applying master theorem, I get m^(lg1) = 1 which is asymptotically smaller than theta(lgm). So I think case 3 of the master theorem  should apply. However, the solution given explains that case 2 of the master theorem applies here which I do not quite understand.

Comment: Hello and welcome to cs.SE! Please edit your question so that it is complete, readable, and detail your own attempts at solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S(n) = T(2^n)$. Write a recurrence formula for S, solve S(n), use that to solve T(n).

Answer (score 1):

T(n) = T(√n) + ϴ(log log n) …….1
Let n = 2<sup>m</sup> 
Taking log2 both side, we get
log<sub>2</sub>n = m           ……2
=>  (log n) /log 2  = m        (using the formula log<sub>a</sub>b = log<sub>m</sub>b /log<sub>m</sub>a)
=>  log n = m x log2
Now, equation 1 becomes
T(2<sup>m</sup>) = T(2<sup>(m/2)</sup>) + ϴ(log (m x log2))
=>  T(2<sup>m</sup>) = T(2<sup>(m/2)</sup>) + ϴ(log (m) + loglog2))
As we know that constant can be ignored hence loglog2 can be ignored
=>  T(2<sup>m</sup>) = T(2<sup>(m/2)</sup>) + ϴ(log m)          …….3
Now, let T(2<sup>m</sup>) = S(m)                ……4
then T(2<sup>(m/2)</sup>) = S(m/2)
So eq. 2 becomes:
S(m) = S(m/2) + ϴ(log m)
Now it is in master’s form, i.e T(n) = aT(n/b) +  ϴ(n<sup>k</sup> x log<sup>p</sup> n)
here a = 1, b= 2, k = 0 , p = 1
which follows the case a = b<sup>k</sup>, where p > -1
Hence S(m) = ϴ(m<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup> x log<sup>(p+1)</sup> m)
=>  S(m) = ϴ(m<sup>log<sub>2</sub>1</sup> x log<sup>2</sup> m)
=>  S(m) = ϴ(m<sup>0</sup> x log<sup>2</sup> m)
=>  S(m) = ϴ(log<sup>2</sup> m)
Substituting S(m) with T(2<sup>m</sup>)  from eq. 4
T(2<sup>m</sup>) = ϴ(log<sup>2</sup> m)
Now substituting the value of m from equation 2, we get
***T(n) = ϴ(log<sup>2</sup> log<sub>2</sub>n)***
Thus it doesn't matter what base is log the answer will be same taking log both side instead of log<sub>2</sub> will make our job more easier.